# Setting a Range for a Textarea based on User Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea and I'm trying to check if someone enters **{{link**  that I can have a modal pop up to let them complete some information.

What I have now is that if someone enters the letter k, it will go back 6 characters and then determine if the text matches **{{link**

But I'm having a problem in setting setting the start and end points for the range. I think that  the problem is with identifying the node, but I'm not sure.

Mainly when someone enters a the letter "k", I'm just trying to go back to check if they had typed: **{{link**  and if they did, it would launch a modal.

This is what I have that isn't working at the part where I'm trying to set the range and get the selection.

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'textarea', function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 75) {

    var end = $('textarea').getCaretPosition();
    var start = end - 6;
    var node = $(this).get(0);

    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(node, start);
    range.setEnd(node, end);

    var selection = range.toString();

        if( selection == '{{link' ){    
            // we'll launch a modal here
        }
    }

});


    $.fn.getCaretPosition = function() {
        var el = $(this).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        if ('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
        } else if ('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
        }
        return pos;
    }
```

This generates the error: Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 at range.setStart(node, start);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean http://jsfiddle.net/sailorob/J6PVJ/

Comment: Thanks very much @Rob. That almost works for me.  The only problem is that the text area might already have some previous instances of {{link on it,then if it does it will trigger on each keyup. The error I get on my code is:  Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 happening at: range.setStart(node, start);

Comment: I've updated it as an object so that you can use it on multiple fields. It simply checks the string backwards for the index of the last occurrence of your trigger string and compares against a stored array of previous triggers, if it's new, it fires. This will not, however, handle the user backspacing and deleting a previously typed  {{link and then retyping it in the same position.